# How to echo all rows (related to DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, distinct-values

This is my [SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/HWASZ21729)

As you can see here, If I use `DISTINCT` then, there are 2 problems

1.)Only 1st `recommendations_vote_average` coloum's number is correct. All other numbers are in wrong order

2.) Only 2 Number get's printed.

If i do not use DISTINCT, all numbers are `7.5` (i.e first vote_average)

How to show all the (10) numbers in correct order?

Expected output

```
movie_title       recommendations_vote_average                    recommendations_title
                                                                  The Dark Knight Rises,Batman Begins,Iron Man,The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King,The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring,The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers,The Matrix,Inception,Iron Man 2,Captain America: The First Avenger
The Dark Knight   7.5,7.5,7.3,8.1,8,7.9,7.9,8,6.6,6.6
```

SQL Fiddle Code:

```
CREATE TABLE tmdb_movies (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmdb_movies (tmdb_id, movie_title) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight');


CREATE TABLE recommendations (
  recommendations_tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  recommendations_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  recommendations_vote_average TEXT NOT NULL
);




INSERT INTO recommendations (recommendations_tmdb_id, recommendations_title, recommendations_vote_average) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight Rises', '7.5'),
(1, 'Batman Begins', '7.5'),
(1, 'Iron Man', '7.3'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '8.1'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring', '8'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '7.9'),
(1, 'The Matrix', '7.9'),
(1, 'Inception', '8'),
(1, 'Iron Man 2', '6.6'),
(1, 'Captain America: The First Avenger', '6.6');


SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_title) as recommendations_title
FROM tmdb_movies 

LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=1

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Comment: Plz add the expected output

Comment: Questions and answers here are long-lived. When we contribute answers, we do so with the hope that other people will benefit from our contributions years from now. Therefore, it's not considered a good idea to put the crux of your question in some other site. Please [edit] your question to put the query here.

Comment: Try `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_vote_average ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) `

Comment: Added expected result @Shibon

Comment: Added @O.Jones bro

Comment: @krokodilko that did not change anything. Just ordered from highest to lowest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess what you want from your question. You mentioned "correct order" without defining it.

[You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in these ways.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
GROUP_CONCAT(a.b)  -- gets all the items in column b -- cardinality preserved

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.b) -- distinct values in column b -- cardinality reduced

GROUP_CONCAT(a.b ORDER BY a.b) -- all items in b in order

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.b ORDER BY a.b) -- distinct items in b in order

GROUP_CONCAT(a.b ORDER BY a.c) -- all items in b in the same order as c
```

I'm not completely sure what it means to an application to add DISTINCT to the last one.

If you're trying to get two concatenated columns in corresponding order, you can't use `DISTINCT` in either one; `DISTINCT` has the potential to remove duplicate values.

Your result set column mentions `_average`. You get an actual average (arithmetic mean) with `AVG(value)`. and that gives a single aggregate number.

If you want a list of scores in one column and a corresponding list of titles in another, try this.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
            recommendations.recommendations_vote_average
   ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title
 ) AS recommendations_vote_average,
GROUP_CONCAT(
            recommendations.recommendations_title
   ORDER BY recommendations.recommendations_title
 ) AS recommendations_title
```

That presents the two concatenated lists in order by the title.

You may not be aware of this: rows in DBMS tables **have no inherent order**. If you say `SELECT * FROM table` (without an `ORDER BY` clause) more than once, and the rows come out in the same order each time, **it is an accident.**   There's nothing in your recommendations table -- no unique id values for example -- to give the order of those items except the scores and the titles. So you may not be able to get the exact order you want.

Many tables contain an autoincrementing `id` column (but yours does not). Using such an `id` column in `ORDER BY` clauses is a way to get repeatable ordering.

**Pro tip:** Denormalized data (comma separated data in columns, for example) is often considered harmful.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` turns normalized data, like your input, into denormalized data. So use it sparingly and only when you need it.

Comment: It changed the order. If i do not use DISTINCT, then all rows are same. If i use it, then the they are in wrong order + only 6 rows echo, like shown in the fiddle.

Comment: Oh, so it is impossible or you did not understand bro? There must be a way. I just want to show the vote_average of the correct recommended movies.

Comment: To get two concat results in corresponding order from `GROUP_CONCAT()`, neither can contain `DISTINCT` and both must contain the same `ORDER BY` clause. That's how you do it in SQL. I don't see a column in your input data that you can use to specify the order you want. You're relying on some kind of natural ordering in your table that SQL does not have.

Answer (score 1):

To get the requested result I think all you need to do is to remove DISTINCT, but I would also recommend introducing an ORDER BY

```
SELECT
      tmdb_movies.movie_title
    , GROUP_CONCAT(r.recommendations_vote_average
                   ORDER BY r.recommendations_vote_average DESC 
                   SEPARATOR ', ' 
                  ) as recommendations
    , GROUP_CONCAT(r.recommendations_title
                   ORDER BY r.recommendations_vote_average DESC 
                   SEPARATOR ', ' 
                  ) as recommendations
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations r ON r.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=1
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
;

              recommendations                |                                 recommendations                                 |
+----+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | The Dark Knight | 8.1, 8, 8, 7.9, 7.9, 7.5, 7.5, 7.3, 6.6, 6.6 | The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, Inception,                       |
|    |                 |                                              | The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring, The Matrix,              |
|    |                 |                                              | The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers, Batman Begins,                           |
|    |                 |                                              | The Dark Knight Rises, Iron Man, Captain America: The First Avenger, Iron Man 2 |
+----+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If it were up to me I would be combining the recommendation score with title (manual line breaks added for presentation):

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |   movie_title   |  recommendations                                                                                                                                                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | The Dark Knight | 8.1(The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King); 
                       | 8(Inception); 8(The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring); 
                       | 7.9(The Matrix); 7.9(The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers); 
                       | 7.5(Batman Begins); 7.5(The Dark Knight Rises); 
                       | 7.3(Iron Man);  6.6(Captain America: The First Avenger);  6.6(Iron Man 2)
```

which was produced by this query:

```
SELECT
      tmdb_movies.movie_title
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT concat(r.recommendations_vote_average,'(',r.recommendations_title,')') 
                   ORDER BY r.recommendations_vote_average DESC 
                   SEPARATOR '; ' 
                  ) as recommendations
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations r ON r.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=1
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

---

more info.
The following query reverses the table precedence and doesn't use group_concat

```
select
    m.movie_title, r.*
from recommendations r
left join tmdb_movies m  ON r.recommendations_tmdb_id=m.tmdb_id
;
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|    |   movie_title   | recommendations_tmdb_id |                 recommendations_title                 | recommendations_vote_average |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | The Dark Knight Rises                                 |                          7.5 |
|  2 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | Batman Begins                                         |                          7.5 |
|  3 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | Iron Man                                              |                          7.3 |
|  4 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King         |                          8.1 |
|  5 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring |                            8 |
|  6 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers                 |                          7.9 |
|  7 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | The Matrix                                            |                          7.9 |
|  8 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | Inception                                             |                            8 |
|  9 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | Iron Man 2                                            |                          6.6 |
| 10 | The Dark Knight |                       1 | Captain America: The First Avenger                    |                          6.6 |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

sample data (should have been in question):

```
CREATE TABLE tmdb_movies (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmdb_movies (tmdb_id, movie_title) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight');


CREATE TABLE recommendations (
  recommendations_tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  recommendations_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  recommendations_vote_average TEXT NOT NULL
);




INSERT INTO recommendations (recommendations_tmdb_id, recommendations_title, recommendations_vote_average) VALUES
(1, 'The Dark Knight Rises', '7.5'),
(1, 'Batman Begins', '7.5'),
(1, 'Iron Man', '7.3'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '8.1'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The The Fellowship of the Ring', '8'),
(1, 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '7.9'),
(1, 'The Matrix', '7.9'),
(1, 'Inception', '8'),
(1, 'Iron Man 2', '6.6'),
(1, 'Captain America: The First Avenger', '6.6');
```

Comment: Brother, can you please not use shortcut? I cannot understand, sorry

Comment: What shortcut? Are you asking for a longer explanation perhaps. Nothing much to say, all I  did was reverse the table precedence of the query and didnt use groip_concat. Thequesy is displayed foryou to consider. I have nothing else worth saying anout the query.

Comment: I need group_concat to echo the data together. Any other solution bro? @used_by_already?

Comment: What - EXACTLY - should the results look like? You need to show us the expeced result. Add this to the question. Do not try to add it as a comment here.

Comment: It is already added @used_By_already. I just want to show the vote_average for the correct movie (and for all)